# How to combine JSON objects with retaining the properties in append (not over write) mode?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to merge two JavaScript (array) Objects into one by combining them

for example:

```
var obj1 = ["apple","banana", "orange"];
var obj2 = ["salad","shack", "juice"];
```

what I want:

```
var objCombined = ["applesalad","bananashack", "orangejuice"]; //if possible with space
```

FYI, I've checked the ***jQuery.extend*** already, please suggest a better alternative.

Thanks,
N Baua

Comment: All of those examples are invalid syntax. What does your real data look like, what do you want the end result to really look like, and what have you tried (other than `jQuery.extend`, which does something quite different)? It's hard to tell given the invalid examples, but if you're really *combining* values, there isn't anything built-in that does it. You'll have to write code.

Comment: have you tried anything? this is solvable with a simple for loop

Comment: Please update the question with valid input and valid output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array for the arrays, because you could easily add some more arrays for longer combined words on each index as result.

Just take the first array as start array and assign a space and the value to each index.

```js
var array1 = ["apple", "banana", "orange"],
  array2 = ["salad", "shack", "juice"],
  result = [array1, array2].reduce(function (a, b) {
      b.forEach(function (v, i) {
          a[i] += ' ' + v;
      });
      return a;
  });
  
console.log(result);
```

Version without mutating `array1`

```js
var array1 = ["apple", "banana", "orange"],
  array2 = ["salad", "shack", "juice"],
  result = [array1, array2].reduce(function (a, b) {
      b.forEach(function (v, i) {
          a[i] = a[i] || '';
          a[i] += (a[i] && ' ') + v;
      });
      return a;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Really nice answer Nina. actually I wanted to use the reduce(), saving the mutating on the arrays indeed. really a nice performer here. I also have a same query for JSON Object {"a","b", "c"} and {"1","2", "3"}, but lets that have on some other day.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj1 = ["apple","banana", "orange"];
var obj2 = ["salad","shack", "juice"];
```

We edit a new container

```
var obj3=Array();
```

now we will launch the following line

```
obj1.forEach(function(item,index){obj3[index]=obj1[index]+" "+obj2[index];});
```

after run, obj3 contains

```
["apple salad", "banana shack", "orange juice"]
```

Comment: Array literals (`var obj3 = []`) should be preferred over the `Array` constructor, due to the [confusing properties of the `Array` constructor](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/#creating-arrays-with-the-array-constructor-instead-of-array-literals).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this

```js
function combine(arr1, arr2) {
    var result = [];

    if (arr1.length === arr2.length) {
      for (var i in arr1) {
        result.push(arr1[i] + ' ' + arr2[i])
      }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Also, you're using curly braces for arrays, you should use backets.